# Git: 'rebase' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: macos, git, github, github-for-mac

I set up [github for mac](http://mac.github.com/)
and now I am trying to use the git command from the terminal.

If I try to run the `git rebase` command I get the following message

```
> cd /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/bin
> git rebase
git: 'rebase' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

>git --help
usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [-c name=value] [--help]
           <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used git commands are:
...
rebase     Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
....
```

So as you can see from the help output the option rebase is present.
What is wrong in my git?

```
git --version
git version 1.7.8.2
```

Comment: What's your `$PATH`?  I would have expected you to have to run `git` from that directory using `./git` and not just `git`, which I would assume picks-up the system-installed version.

Answer (score 8):

For me, I found that to fix this error message ("`'rebase' is not a git command`") I needed to  [set up Git "exec-path", either via command-line](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/issues/491#issuecomment-3603531) for one-shot use, or better [via environment variable](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/):

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/PATH/TO/git/libexec/git-core
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the Git build that comes with GitHub for Mac. They (GitHub, that is) probably modified the binary to remove features that GitHub for Mac doesn't use.

You should really install your 'own' Git. I recommend using Homebrew: [Link](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: Is there any reason for Github-for-mac if it removes features (functionality), but doesn't describe what's removed / what's left ?

Comment: File size would be my guess. Remember, the git build inside GitHub for Mac is buried deep inside the package. It's not at all meant to be used standalone by anyone. Spending a lot of time adjusting documentation (like git --help) would seem pointless.

Answer (score 0):

This occasionally occurs to me, but only in association with changes in Xcode installation or macOS installs.

The Xcode command line tools need re-installing:

```
 $ xcode-select --install
```

This is will launch the GUI for installing those tools. Once this finishes, `git` works as expected.